# Facebook post page feed as page admin

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
        var message = 'test';
        var picture = 'http://l.yimg.com/f/i/tw/ks/show/120604_mntl01.jpg';
        var link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIl8Px1ds3c';
        var name = 'great';
        var description = 'des';


        FB.api('/1437247769881131/feed', 'post', {message: message, picture: picture, name: name, description: description },function (response){
        if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
        } else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
                });
```

I tried posting a test message to my fan page wall , but it become a visitor post(on left)

How could i post to the wall , if i change my admin to fan page admin ,it pop up a dialog

[You're using Facebook as a Page]

[To continue, you'll need to switch from using Facebook as 談政宏 to using Facebook as 談政宏.]

So i change back to person admin , but i can only post a visitor post

How can I post as Page Admin ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a Page Token to post "as Page". Right now you are using a User Token so it will get posted "as User". Information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: that´s what i said, yes ;)